# Database access pattern using PostgreSQL and ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, database, server

I am planning to connect to a PostgreSQL DBs on a server from ArcGIS on my laptop. My server admin is interested to know "The access pattern: How, when, how often, (would ArcGIS access the DBs) during the execution of a job. In order words, the workflow of your data analysis process." Does anyone know the details behind the execution?

Edited: Some ArcGIS tools I will be using include buffer, clip, spatial join and detect feature changes

Comment: Would depend on what your actually doing with the data, how often you're using it.  What jobs are you executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS, assuming you are browsing the data, doing edits, analysis and what not, needs virtually "continuous" access to the database. Each zoom or pan request will trigger SQL statements send to the database to get the latest results. You are live on the database with ArcGIS Server (ArcSDE).

If your administrator is not familiar with (ESRI) GIS and is thinking in the "old school" ETL way of accessing the geographic data (Extract-Transform-Load), where you only hit the database upon extracting some data, and putting it back in a single load process after you've done something with it, he is in for a bad day...

I think it wise if you point your administrator to relevant ESRI documentation and Help pages, to get a feel of what ArcGIS does in terms of providing connections to enterprise databases.

E.g. following pages might be a good start:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdb-architecture/what-is-a-geodatabase.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/administer-gdb-intro/geodatabase-administration.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/gdb-architecture/geodatabase-transaction-management.htm

He should probably also be reading the highly recommended ESRI maintained **System Design Strategies** pages:

http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/System_Design_Strategies_Preface